# Eclipse IDE crashes after pressing "<" button while editing XML file on MAC Ventura

Tags: eclipse, crash, macos-ventura

Currently I'm using Eclipse IDE:
Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)
Build id: 20221201-1913

It seems to be the latest. My MacOS is Ventura 13.1

As I said, the app crashes everytime upon pressing the "<" button, while the ">" button works perfectly fine. Asking here to see if anyone have the same problem and how to fix it

Nothing I could do about it due the app crashes immediately

Comment: Is it a particular XML file? All of them?

Comment: There was a problem with crashes on Ventura which was fixed in Ventura 13.2, but I'm not sure if it would cause this crash.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug of macOS Ventura 13.1 that has been **fixed in Ventura 13.2**.

For details see:

- [Eclipse SWT issue #480 - *Eclipse 4.25 x86_64 keep crashing when using the JS editor on MacOS Ventura*](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/480)
- [WebKit Bug 247387 - *REGRESSION(macOS Ventura): OpenAudible, Eclipse and other Java applications crash when using WebKit*](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=247387)

In your case, typing `<` triggers the code completion that uses the browser widget to display information for the currently selected proposal, and using the browser widget causes the crash in Ventura 13.1.

Comment: From reading, it seems to be a bug in Webkit, not in macOS?

Comment: @user253751 As I understand it, it is a bug in the WebKit that is part of macOS, not in something that is installed in macOS. So the only way to get the fix is to upgrade to Ventura 13.2 or higher.